# Directly (NOT iteratively) maximizing (1 << n) subject to (a & ~((1 << n) - 1)) >= b

Tags: c, binary, bit-manipulation, boolean-logic, maximize

I'm trying to find the largest `1 << n` that satisfies this inequality (all variables are positive integers):

```
a & ~((1 << n) - 1) >= b
```

Solving this iteratively is trivial (and yes, I know you can get better performance through divide-and-conquer and the like), but that's not my question.

I'm wondering if there is a way this could be solved **directly**, like through bit-twiddling of some sort?

***Note 1:*** Assume you can do "round up/down to the closest power of 2" in one operation.
***Note 2:*** If necessary, you can assume a two's complement representation (but I doubt this helps).

What technique can I use to solve this, if there is a direct way? If there isn't, can I tell somehow?

I've tried lots of things like XORing `a` and `b`, rounding the result up to the next power of 2, etc. but I didn't end up finding anything nice that always works.

Comment: 'all variables are positive integers' do you mean that all variables are of type `unsigned`?

Comment: @Marian: Sure, why not... you can just cast them to signed or unsigned if they're not, that's not really the issue.

Comment: Isn't this equivalent to finding the leading bit of `a & ~b` ?

Comment: It's not. For example, with a == b, n is the number of trailing zeros in a, but a & ~b is always 0.

Comment: @user2357112: Good point, but I'm not actually too worried about those edge cases, since it's just one operation to check (`a == b ? blah : blah`)... though it'd be nice if it always works.

Comment: If `a==b` then the answer is 0. If `a<b` then there is no answer. If `a>b` then you need to find the most significant bit that is `1` in `a` and `0` in `b`. Which is to say that I agree with Marian.

Comment: Um... The problem seems to be "interesting" if and only if the highest-order (HO) bit in `a` occupies the same position as in `b`. In all other cases the problem becomes trivial: if HO bit in `a` is higher than in `b`, then the inequlity will always hold untill you wipe all bits in `a`; if HO bit in `a` is lower than in `b`, then the inequlity will never hold.

Comment: @AnT: Yes, I intended to solve it for the cases when the HO bit is at the same position for both.

Comment: @Marian: I finally checked, and I'm not quite sure why you think it's the same as `a & ~b`. For example, if you have `a = 7`, `b = 4`, then you get `(a & ~b) = (7 & ~4) = 3`, but the answer is `(1 << n) = 4` because `(7 & ~(4 - 1)) = (7 & ~3) = 4 >= 4`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @user3386109: In my comment above, the leading bit of `(7 & ~4) = 3` would `2`, not `4`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (a < b) {
    oops();
} else if (a == b) {
    return ctz(a);
} else {
    // most significant mismatching bit - must be set to 1 in a and 0 in b
    int msmb = round_down_to_power_of_2(a ^ b);
    if (b & (msmb - 1)) {
        return ctz(msmb);
    } else {
        return ctz(b);
    }
}
```

We have 4 cases:

1. If a < b, no value of n works.
2. If a == b, we can clear every bit up to the least significant set bit of a.
3. If a > b and b has set bits below the most significant mismatching bit between a and b, we can clear every bit up to the most significant mismatching bit.
4. If a > b and b has no set bits below the most significant mismatching bit between a and b, we can clear every bit up to the least significant set bit of b.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Oh, right, you want 1 << n, not n. I'm returning n.

Comment: Yeah I'm not thinking properly today, didn't notice that :) let me check it some more...

Comment: Seems you're right! Thank you! Looking at it now, I think I got something similar before but I didn't bother finishing it. I'll probably try to clean up this one :)

Comment: It's worth mentioning how to do `ctz(x)` by the way, because this is somewhat cheating since I didn't say it was allowed in the question. (You can do it via `1 << ctz(x) = round_down_to_pow2(x & (~x + 1))`.)